# cant add the twilio-python library to a Google App Engine project

Tags: python, google-app-engine, twilio

hi I have been trying to add twilio-python library to a google app engine project.As recommended I followed the steps from the link below:http://twilio-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/appengine.html.

However,I am encountering error messages about which I am a bit clueless.I am providing the log of my app engine launcher

Please have a look and let me know what am I doing wrong.

Heres the log message :

```
*** Running dev_appserver with the following flags:
    --skip_sdk_update_check=yes --port=12081 --admin_port=8005
Python command: /usr/bin/python2.7
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/dev_appserver.py", line 83, in <module>
    _run_file(__file__, globals())
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/dev_appserver.py", line 79, in _run_file
    execfile(_PATHS.script_file(script_name), globals_)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/devappserver2.py", line 1040, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/devappserver2.py", line 1033, in main
    dev_server.start(options)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/devappserver2.py", line 758, in start
    options.config_paths, options.app_id)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/application_configuration.py", line 831, in __init__
    module_configuration = ModuleConfiguration(config_path, app_id)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/application_configuration.py", line 127, in __init__
    self._config_path)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/application_configuration.py", line 424, in _parse_configuration
    config, files = appinfo_includes.ParseAndReturnIncludePaths(f)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/api/appinfo_includes.py", line 82, in ParseAndReturnIncludePaths
    appyaml = appinfo.LoadSingleAppInfo(appinfo_file)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/api/appinfo.py", line 2214, in LoadSingleAppInfo
    raise appinfo_errors.EmptyConfigurationFile()
google.appengine.api.appinfo_errors.EmptyConfigurationFile
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

App Engine tried to load an empty configuration file, your `app.yaml` file. Hence it's throwing an `EmptyConfigurationFile` error. App engine needs to be informed about some basic configuration parameters to start serving your app, however basic it is.

The following is a basic `app.yaml` config file structured for your example:

```
application: twilio-demo
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

handlers:
- url: .*
  script: helloworld.app
```

You can read more on [Configuring with app.yaml](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig?hl=en)